# Change browser fingerprints in chrome using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, fingerprint, chrome-options

I have such a problem. I can't spoof chrome browser data through selenium. I don't understand how to replace the data. I need to replace canvas, wavegl, and other data. I have a fingerprint file. But I don't understand how to connect them all to chrome. I tried to replace the rendered data, i.e. GPU data. But nothing happened. help me please

I tried through ChromeOptions items. An example of user-agent substitution is --user-agent. This changed for me, but everything else seemed to work in conjunction with several elements and I could not connect everything. I tried turning off the GPU and replacing it with my own values.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what to add. There are no errors because there is no code. I wanted to know where to get information, links, sites, in order to at least somehow understand how to add parameters to Chrome through Selenium.